# Oracle query really slow when comparing two values of type Date

Tags: oracle

I'm querying against a view in Oracle, I'm not sure if it's relevant but just in case I'm copying the code that generates the view:

```
    select distinct cpc.Column1, cpc.Column2, //some other fields.. 
    from Table1 cpc inner join Table2 cpob on cpc.brand = cpob.brand 
    and cpc.ship = cpob.ship inner join Table3 cpvi on cpc.voyage = cpvi.voyage
```

These queries are fast:

```
select * from   MyView where rownum <=500 //fast
select * from   MyView where  VOYAGE >= '07-JUL-15'  and rownum <=500 //fast
select * from   MyView where   VOYAGE <= '07-JUL-17' and rownum <=500 //fast
```

But when I need to retrieve data according to a range of dates it lasts like 40 seconds... no good

```
select * from MyView where voyage >= '07-JUL-15' 
and voyage <= '07-JUL-17' and rownum <=500  //too slow --- around 40 seconds!
```

Same thing when using `between` instead of `where ... and ...` too slow..
I've created indexes for `voyage` on the table but it's still to slow. Any ideas to improve the performance of this query? Why is that slow only when I add `where voyage >= '07-JUL-15' 
and voyage <= '07-JUL-17'`? and not for the other queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not comparing dates, you are comparing strings.  Assuming that `voyage` is of type `DATE`, it is being coerced to a string (using whatever the default date format is in your database or session) for comparison with the string literals you are providing in the query.  This can cause all kinds of madness in the Oracle query optimizer.

I suggest that you explicitly convert the strings to dates, e.g.:

```
VOYAGE >= TO_DATE('07-JUL-15','DD-MON-YY')
```

or use date literals, e.g.:

```
VOYAGE >= date '2015-07-07'
```

This may or may not improve your query performance, but with the information you've given, it is my best advice.  When asking questions about query performance in Oracle, it is more helpful to include the actual table/view definition, any indexes present on the table(s), and the actual query execution plan Oracle is using.

(Also, I just noticed your view includes a DISTINCT operator. This is often not conducive to good query performance. Please consider whether you have used DISTINCT to cover up some logical flaw in the view definition that causes it to produce duplicates.)

Comment: I modified the view to not use distinct and the query is very fast now(just a few ms). Any guess of why it was so slow using distinct?

Comment: Slow query performance is often caused by Oracle using a non-optimal execution plan.  Having a DISTINCT operation can make this more likely.  One reason is that it makes the optimizer's estimates of row counts less accurate.  Another is that it can prevent or discourage the optimizer from pushing predicates inside a view or subquery (in this example, that means it might execute the view query, store those results in memory, then apply your predicate filters).  Again, seeing the actual execution plans would be necessary to say anything definitive.

Comment: this is funny, I was curious and recreated the view as it was before using distinct to generate execution plans and see what was happening but now it runs fast... so I'm not sure of what happened there, thanks!!

Comment: Apparently it was faster because it was being cached by Oracle, I realized later about that, I've created a new question with more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252842/optimize-totimespan-query-within-oracle . Not sure if you could take a look to it and have any guess, thanks!